# ¿Cómo solucionar problema de post en flask_restful?

Tags: post, flask-restful

Al realizar el POST

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/bot?id_articulo=1&url_articulo=https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_input.asp

a una API en Postman obtengo el siguiente mensaje

> "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Mi código es el siguiente

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Bot(Resource):

    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  
        parser.add_argument('id_articulo', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('url_articulo', required=True)
        args = parser.parse_args() 

        data_articulo = pd.read_csv('articulos.csv')

        if args['url_articulo'] in list(data_articulo['url_articulo']):
            return {
                'mensage': f"El artículo '{args['url_articulo']}' ya existe."
            }, 409
        else:
            nueva_columna = pd.DataFrame({
                'id_articulo':  [args['id_articulo']],
                'url_articulo': [args['url_articulo']],
            })

            data_articulo = data_articulo.append(nueva_columna, ignore_index=True)
            data_articulo.to_csv('articulos.csv', index=False)  
            return {'data': data_articulo.to_dict()}, 200 

api.add_resource(Bot, '/bot')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Tengo entendido que de ser un problema extenrno a flask_restful, el mensaje que me saldría sería sobre internal server error, así que no creo que esté relacionado con mi archivo csv.

No tengo idea de lo que está saliendo mal y me gustaría saber la forma correcta de lograr que esto funcione.

**Actualización**

Noté que el problema está relacionado con el entorno virtual en el que estoy trabajando, el archivo requirements.txt contiene los siguiente

```
aniso8601==9.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pytz==2022.1
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.1.2
zipp==3.8.0
aniso8601==9.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
numpy==1.23.1
pandas==1.4.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.1.2
zipp==3.8.0
```

Esto lo noté, pues al ejecutar la aplicación desde fuera del ambiente virtual este funciona sin problemas.